# Como atribuir valores a um Array associativo em php?

Tags: php, foreach, array-associativo

Num array, por exemplo:

```
$arr = array('item1', 'item2' ... 'itemN');
```

quero atribuir um valor a cada item. Para isso, tentei um foreach:

```
foreach($arr as $a => $b)
    $b = 4;
```

mas é informado pela IDE (phpStorm) que a variável local não usada; 
`(unused local variable '$b')`

Como atribuo um valor a um item desse array??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça a atribuição passando a chave, isso serve tanto para arrays associativos quanto númericos. Então basta combinar a chave (`$key`) com o array e atribuir o novo valor.

```
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $arr[$key] = 'novo valor';
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Obrigado!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Tem um outro jeito ainda, que é usando referência.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => &$value) {
    $value = 'novo valor';
}

unset($value); // Tem que apagar, pois o último sempre fica como referência.
```

Ao usar o sinal `&$value`, o valor passado para atual da iteração do `foreach` estará apontando para o valor original do `array`, porém como referência. Se você alterá-lo, o valor atual apontado também será alterado.

Note que ao final eu usei um `unset`, pois se não fizesse assim, ao alterar o valor `$value` fora do `foreach`, o último elemento do `$arr` seria modificado.