# É possível encontrar 'this' em um foreach?

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte script:

```
$arr = [
   10 => [
      'Xa' => 'xA'
   ],
   32 => [
      'Xb' => 'xB'
   ],
   45 => [
      'Xc' => 'xC'
   ],
   78 => [
      'Xd' => 'xD'
   ]
]
foreach($arr as $var){

   if($var['Xa'] == 'xA'){
      //Nesta escapatória encontrar 'this' para modificar $arr[10] 
   }
}
```

- É possível encontrar `'this'` dentro de `if` sem usar `'key'` ?

O contexto da questão é que, em determinado loop (de uma array não sequencial crescente) eu preciso acrescentar dados a essa array, e não consigo acessar sua chave pois são dados alguns unsets no momento da construção.

Anteriormente ela funcionava com isso (antes de adicionar os unsets), porém não está funcionando mais e está adicionando a chaves que não existem mais na array:

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($return as $rs_row) {
    foreach ($rs_flag as $flag) {
        if ($rs_row['id'] == $flag['relationship']) {
            $return[$c]['flag'] = $flag['flag'];
            $return[$c]['flag-cod'] = $flag['cod'];
            $return[$c]['flag-observations'] = $flag['observations'];
        }
    }
    $c += 1;
}
```

Comment: Já perguntaram isso aqui. Acho que foi o Wallace. Vou procurar. Só que o "foco" era resgatar o índice em um loop...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sabe o link dessa pergunta ? eu só achei pra encontrar o indice, eu não posso/não quero isso pois os indices são embaralhados, preciso de alguma forma encontrar 'this' ou refazer a parte que constrói essa array pra que ela mantenha a sequencia.

Comment: Talvez ajude: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/154082/64969; não é exatamente uma duplicata, me enganei... mas lá mostra como transformar um `array` em um par chave/valor, que creio ser positivo pro seu caso

Comment: vc quer pegar o indice do elemento atual? `key()` ou `array_keys()` não ajudam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução foi encontrada logo após a pergunta, bastou apenas adicionar o captador da chave:

```
foreach ($return as $rs_key => $rs_row) {
    foreach ($rs_flag as $flag) {
        if($rs_row['id'] == $flag['relationship']) {
            $return[$rs_key]['flag'] = $flag['flag'];
            $return[$rs_key]['flag-cod'] = $flag['cod'];
            $return[$rs_key]['flag-observations'] = $flag['observations'];
        }
    }
}
```

Outro porém, por desatenção eu estava errando a sintaxe:

- Correto

  ```
  foreach($arr as $key => $target) {
      //
  }
  ```
- Errado (como eu estava fazendo)

  ```
  foreach($arr as $key -> $target) {
      //
  }
  ```

com isso eu recebia um erro e conclui que não conseguia acessar a array erroneamente.